# Is it possible to log the progress during a webpack build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When I am running linting I get errors if something is wrong, otherwise I get no notification that the linting i executed. Is it possible to add logging messages after plugins or loaders are executed?

In my particular case I would like to add log messages after the "StyleLintPlugin"-plugin and "tslint"-loader. See the Webpack config below.

```js
import path from 'path';
import StyleLintPlugin from 'stylelint-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/index"),
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  target: 'web',
  watch: true, //Rebuild when file is changed
  devtool: 'source-map', //Let us debug the code without being modified
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.css', '.scss']
  },
  plugins: [
    //Used to lint sass files
    new StyleLintPlugin({
      configFile: '.stylelintrc',
      context: undefined,
      files: ['**/*.s?(a|c)ss'],
      failOnError: true,
      quiet: false
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modeules/,
        loader: 'tslint'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modeules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modeules/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modeules/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
      }
    ],
  },
  tslint: {
    emitErrors: true,
    failOnHint: true
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the need of log when there is no error or warning in the code?

Comment: When I was messing around with the config I was putting the "plugins"-section under module (by misstake). There was no errors, but with logging I would (maybe) have seen that the log was missing.

Comment: When you dont have any lint error/warnings, you wont get logs

Comment: And there is no way to get it?

Comment: You can write your own plugin to display the logs. Follow [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html)

Comment: If that is the only solution I guess I have to survive without it. Thanks for the tip anyway, if I get some spare time I will look into it. 

Without any knowledge about how the plugins are written, I doubt that I can get information about if other plugins/loaders finished their execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log to node console or debug during webpack build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30745505/476716).